# JavaScript: Merge Objects inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

i have an array (0,...,n) and with several object. The array can be of any length.

```
array = {{name: alice, age: 18, hobby: dance}, {name:bob, age: 27, hobby: cars}, {name: chloe, age:45, hobby: painting}};
```

Now I want a new array. This new array should look like that:

```
new array = {alice, bob, chloe};
```

I can merge this objects with a for-loop. But is there a simple join or merge function which I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you want to extract a particular property value from each  object in the original array, which you can do with `.map()`. However, that operation does not really seem like "merging" in any sense.

Comment: It's worth noting that what you have isn't an array, or even a valid structure at all...

Comment: Neither the input nor the desired output makes sense. The input is not valid JavaScript, and the output (and input) expects variables with the names `alice`, `bob` and `chloe` which are not defined, and the output is not an array. The keyword `new` is not valid there either.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just use `map` ;)

```js
let array = [{name: alice, age: 18, hobby: dance}, {name:bob, age: 27, hobby: cars}, {name: chloe, age:45, hobby: painting}];

let result = array.map(i => i.name)
```

Comment: Instead of "answering" a non-question, you could spend three minutes to find a matching duplicate or simply cast a close vote. This would be far more beneficial for the community. And no, `i` is not a good name for an object.

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand what you mean.

your origin array

array = [{name: alice, age: 18, hobby: dance}, {name:bob, age: 27, hobby: cars}, {name: chloe, age:45, hobby: painting}];

the new array you want get

new array = [alice, bob, chloe];

you can use

```js
array.map(o => ({ [o.name]: o }))
```

Is this the answer you want?